# google closure library rich text editor

Tags: google-closure-library

I want a standalone [rich text editor](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html) from [google closure library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) but it does

have a lot of files is there a **minified version**

just for the [text editor](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html) to download

i spend 4 hours and i couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of - that would be sidestepping the Closure Compiler.

While the Google Closure Tools comes with the 'Closure Compiler' that minifies the code for you, it obfuscates the code as well. To accomplish your goal, you could hypothetically compile the code with the Closure Compiler and use the [`goog.exportSymbol`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/base.js#1424) function to make your own minimized version with unobfuscated endpoints for your other JavaScript code, which would control when and how the editor was rendered.

IMHO, this sounds like a lot of work to pull out one component of the Google Closure Library. You should probably use the raw files and run them through some third-party minimizer that maintains the names of functions and properties, or you could use another component entirely. The compilation technique only has positives if you plan to use more of the Google Closure Library in the future.

Have you considered using the [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) component? It may meet your needs better than taking half a step into the Google Closure Library.